# Python raw_input() unable to paste in windows?

Tags: python

Is there a simple module that let's you paste input in python ? 
Asking someone to type letter by letter is kinda harsh .
By default a .py file is opened with python.exe if is installed and this does not allow "rightclick+paste" in the console .So how can i make this happen with python ? i think this would be more of a exact question .

Comment: If you are speaking of Windows Command, the icon at the top left has a context menu with an Edit->Paste option. May not be exactly what you want, but it's available.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. What's the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: This isn't really a Python issue. This is a `cmd.exe` issue.

Comment: By default a .py file is opened with python.exe if is installed and this does not allow "rightclick+paste" in the console .So how can i make this happen with python ? i think this would be more of a exact question .

Answer (score 0):

You can make this by open cmd.exe and type here "C:\Python32\python".
Path is depend on the version of python. Mine is 3.2.

Comment: The thing is i don't want to open python , i want to open myscript.py that will ask for input .So if you double click a .py file it will be opened by python.exe by default. SO i guess i have to convert it to a .exe some how .

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to simply paste something into the windows command prompt, John Giotta is correct that a user can click on the little icon in the top left.

I imagine, however, that you're looking for a way that a user can input a large amount of text, without typing it in line by line. A simple way to do this, would be to let the user input a file name, which python would then read. Perhaps something like this is what you're looking for:

```
while True:
    filename = raw_input("Path to file to be read: ")
    try:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            contents = f.read()
        break
    except IOError:
        print "That was not a valid file \n"
```

This loop will keep asking the user for a file until then enter a valid path. When they enter a valid path, it will be read in as a string to the contents variable. This way, a user could enter a large amount of text into a file, and then you simply prompt them for the path to the file.

You can read up on file input more [In the docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Comment: i guess the file approach is the easiest way to do this  , i em actually asking for a link as input . But i guess i can take the .txt path .